# How to format excel by java spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, format

I exported a excel file, as picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im4PH.png)

I want to edit "align_center" for text in the sheet. When I merger two row so I want to format "center" for it. 
This is code it's back-end :

```
CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        headerCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        // Row for Header
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        // Header
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNTASK.length; col++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(COLUMNTASK[col]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }
for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNTASK.length; col++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(COLUMNTASK[col]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }
        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < allTasks.size()-1; i++) {
            count = i;
            for (int j = count+1; j < allTasks.size(); j++) {
                if (allTasks.get(i).getUserName().equals(allTasks.get(j).getUserName())) {
                    count++;
                } else if (count != i) {
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(i+1, count+1, 0, 0));
                    i = count;
                } else if (count == i) {
                    break;
                }

                if (count == allTasks.size()-1) {
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(i+1, count+1, 0, 0));
                    i = count;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int rowIdx = 1;
        for (WorkingTimeReportResponse workingTimeReportResponse : allTasks) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(workingTimeReportResponse.getUserName());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(workingTimeReportResponse.getProjectName());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(workingTimeReportResponse.getIssue());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(workingTimeReportResponse.getTotalHours());
        }
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you want to center align? Headers are already center aligned. Also which cells need to be merged.

Comment: do you see picture? I want to center for all text in the sheet.

Comment: I merged it. because the question very long so I remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is necessary set the style in all cells like you did in headers cell.

First, create a styel for regular cells:

```
CellStyle regularCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
regularCellStyle setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

After, create the cell and store it in a variable.

```
Cell cellA = row.createCell(0);
cellA.setCellValue(workingTimeReportResponse.getUserName());
cellA.setCellStyle(regularCellStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks! we should format vertical so it is beautiful more. "contentStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);"

Comment: Great¡ im happy for help you. Consider mark the my answer as solution :)